# Could not parse sql timestamp string error message

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, sybase-asa

At the point of posting a record to a database table I get the following error:

> Could not parse sql timestamp string.

At the click of a button my code does the following:

```
qry1.Open;
qry1.Insert;
qry1.FieldByName('files_uploaded').asdatetime := qry2.FieldByName('files_uploaded').asdatetime;
qry1.Post;
qry1.Close;
```

The datatype for the field in the database table is `timestamp`.

Example of the data in the field : `2014-04-23T14:48:40.816+01:00`.

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong or unless its something to do with the field data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A timestamp column does not contain a date/time. It is a numeric value incremented by Sybase automatically each time a row is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting ".Value" instead of defining the Data Type. When you use **.Value** the dataset will convert everything that is necessary.

```
qry1.Open;
qry1.Insert;
qry1.FieldByName('files_uploaded').Value :=qry2.FieldByName('files_uploaded').Value;
qry1.Post;
qry1.Close;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
qry1.Open;
qry1.Insert;
qry1.FieldByName('files_uploaded').AsSQLTimeStamp :=qry2.FieldByName('files_uploaded').AsSQLTimeStamp;
qry1.Post;
qry1.Close;
```

Comment: Why? What difference does that make?